# Start Airflow Celery Flower UI with purge settings

Tags: airflow, celery, flower

Every time we remove a node from the cluster, and add a new celery node and worker, we notice that the old node shows offline. We wanted to remove those using the option mentioned here:

```
https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#purge-offline-workers
```

We tried to run the below command but it is not working:
`/usr/local/bin/airflow celery flower --purge_offline_workers=20`

Comment: Ever figure this out?